# Is changing an access modifier in .NET from private to public in share component a breaking change?

Tags: c#, .net

Lets consider a theoretical example

- `ApplicationA`
- `SharedLibrary` -> `ClassA`
- `Plugin`

If you change a `ClassA` in `SharedLibrary`, update `ApplicationA` to use the new `SharedLibrary` but do NOT update the `Plugin`. Would you still be able to load the `Plugin` (via a Assembly.CreateInstance or MEF)?

In .NET is changing an access modifier from `private` -> `public` a breaking change?

This article seems to imply even adding something would be a breaking change, however talks about overloads, etc, not modifiers.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2012/01/09/every-public-change-is-a-breaking-change/

**EDIT**: The `ShareLibrary` class is used in the `Plugin`. Hence the reason for asking.

Regards

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: Title and body disagree. Which direction are you making the change? I'd assume the one in the title since it's the more likely to be questionable.

Comment: "Breaking change" has no hard definition. For any change you can make to a public interface, maybe so simple as adding something, someone can come up with an example that  will break after that change. The question is if that example is to obscure **for you** to qualify as breaking change or not. Other may have their personal  diverging opinion.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks man, sorry mistake was in the body :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, making a `private` member `public` can break the build.

Consider this class:

```
public class Test
{
    private int Method(int x = 0) => x;
    public int Method(int x = 1, int y = 2) => x + y;

    public int Foo => Method(0);
}
```

And this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new Test().Method());
    }
}
```

This will compile OK, and will print `3`.

Now if you make public the private overload of `Method()` the code above will no longer compile. You will get the following compile error:

```
Error   CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 
'Test.Method(int)' and 'Test.Method(int, int)'
```

However, with regard to your question about the plugin - you did not specify whether it uses `SharedLibrary`. If it doesn't, then changing `SharedLibrary` cannot break the plugin.

If it does, then you *could* get a nasty runtime error, depending on how it uses it - but that's actually not guaranteed to happen.

---

Here's an example of using a plugin which WILL break at runtime if you make a method public.

Firstly, we have a shared class library containing the following class:

```
public class Test
{
    private int Method(int x = 0) => x;
    public int Method(int x = 1, int y = 2) => x + y;

    public int Foo => Method(0);
}
```

Secondly, we have a plugin class that uses that library using reflection like so:

```
public class Plugin
{
    public int Test()
    {
        var testClass = typeof(Test);
        var testInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(testClass);
        var method = testClass.GetMethod("Method");
        int result = (int)method.Invoke(testInstance, new object[]{1, 2});
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now suppose we have an application that uses the shared class, and also contains a copy of the plugin assembly DLL in its output folder:

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(new Test().Method(1, 2));

    var plugin       = Assembly.LoadFile(Path.GetFullPath("PluginLibrary.dll"));
    var testClass    = plugin.GetType("PluginLibrary.Plugin");
    var testInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(testClass);
    var method       = testClass.GetMethod("Test");
    int result       = (int) method.Invoke(testInstance, null);

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

This will run ok.

Now suppose you make the `private int Method(int x = 0)` public and recompile the shared class library and the application that uses it, but DO NOT recompile the plugin - i.e. you continue using the old plugin DLL.

Now if you run the program you'll get an `Ambiguous match found` exception.

This is an example where you have broken an unchanged plugin by making public a method that wasn't even being used by that plugin.

Comment: Thank you. Yes the plugin would be making use of the SharedLibrary.

Answer (score 2):

From the website you linked :
Some public surface area breaking changes are obvious: making a public method into a private method

Yes it is a breaking change but if you don't use this class and method in the plugin,  it won't break your program.
You may change your architecture to rely on interfaces instead of implementations in your plugins.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I've deleted the answer for it was wrong. :)

Comment: Changing the architecture would not be possible. The whole idea is to minimize the extent of the changes, to the point where I don't even want to recompile the plugins.

Comment: It might be interesting for a next version of you want to build something more reliable / future proof or for your next project with plugins ;)